# How can I set the icon appear in the right side of the component @mui/Chip?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sx

I am using **MUI v5.15.0** . I Have a **Chip** component and I want the icon to appear after the label in the right side.

I tried using the following css - `.MuiChip-icon{ order:1 }` but it shows too much gap. It also makes the icon appear outside the border
[Here is the Chip after applying the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qLgH.png)

I also added some padding with the sx api to fix the above. but there is too much gap between the label and icon and here is the final code

```
<Chip
     label={"Trip "+props.tripNumber}
     variant="outlined"
     onClick={handleClick}
     icon={<ArrowForwardOutlined />}
     sx={{ borderColor: "#0049AF", display: 'flex', paddingRight: "10px" }}
/>
```

[Here is the Chip after applying the padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5Mz.png)

Answer (score 1):

The MUI v5 documentation [contains examples](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/#custom-delete-icon) of putting an icon to the right of the label by setting the `deleteIcon` property.  You can set `onDelete={() => {}}`.

Comment: I tried this. But this option gives different effect on click. Also the icon color doesn't exactly works as expected .